# Is there an AJAX command I can use to debug PHP variables without breaking AJAX call?

Tags: 7, ajax, debugging

I know [the list of Ajax framework commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7). Every one of them is doing something useful. But sometimes I want, for debug, include a piece of debug data in my AJAX response. I want it to be unobtrusive, so `var_dump` is out. I need to wrap my debug data in some kind of command. On the other hand, I will view it using JS console, so I don't want it to actually change anything on my page. And changing something hidden with CSS is not feasible - I'm not in charge of CSS here. So it leaves me with commands approach.

Which command could I use for this purpose?

I was thinking about [`ajax_command_append`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_append/7) with selector that will never be found, but I don't want to introduce any additional errors in my JavaScript Console.

Debugging it with xdebug is not, currently, possible, and I would rather avoid spending time and resources on creating VM, when what I need is something I can do with simple `var_dump` on non-AJAX pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't such logging or "nulling" Ajax command. That doesn't mean you can't build any! I for example, have created some custom Ajax commands, and also a `eval()` so I can run some quick codes.

**1: Define the JS action**

You need to add a new JS  file, or merge as necessary. Note this `document.ready` event is important (this is just the definition, so no need to be a `behavior`).

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
        Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.js_eval = function(ajax, data, status) {
            eval(data.script);
        };
        Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.console_log = function(ajax, data, status) {
            console.log(data.var);
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**2: The Ajax render array**

Assuming you are aware of the `ajax_render()` and JS renderable arrays, it's time to create your own custom command.

```
function mymodule_ajax_command_js_eval($script) {
  return array(
    'command' => 'js_eval',
    'script' => $script,
    'my_custom' => 'my custom value',
  );
}
function mymodule_ajax_command_console_log(&$var) {
  return array(
    'command' => 'console_log',
    'var' => $var,
  );
}
```

Above PHP function is not really a hook, and can be any name you want. For the sake of convention, I'm using `ajax_command` in the function name.  In the return array, `command` will be called from `Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands` scope. You can pass additional variables, and they will be in the `data` for JS to access (`data.my_custom`, `data.script`, likewise.)

**3: Now call it!**

Now that you have the JS and PHP ends, time to call the function!

```
$output = array();
// $output[] = ajax_command_append('#some_random_id_that_you_d_normally_use', $html);
$output[] = mymodule_ajax_command_js_eval("alert('Big Bang Theory S8!)");
$output[] = mymodule_ajax_command_console_log($stuff_you_d_normally_dpm);

print ajax_render($output);
exit;
```

Comment: Apart from using `eval()` that looks great - why not just pipe the data straight through to `console.log`?

Comment: I just updated my question. It's actually possible to create pretty and more straight forward commands. My example in particular is using eval() because I wasn't sure what commands OP wanted to run exactly. Defining the eval saved a lot time when debugging stuff :)

Comment: AyeshK All I wanted was to see some data from php variable in my ajax output, without breaking AJAX. So if you will incorporate suggestion by @Clive , your answer will be **exactly** what I need.

Comment: Just added `mymodule_ajax_command_console_log` example.

Comment: Will need to play a bit more, but looks like what I needed, thank you.

Comment: @AyeshK i took the liberty of editing one of your strings, I'm positive you meant `console_log` instead of `js_eval` for the 2nd command